# submit two file input fields in the same form

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, metabox, attachments

I have a form which has two file input fields, each input should be submitted in different metabox in custom post type, when I try to submit the form it takes only the first one and ignore the second one!

here is my form

```
<form method="POST" name="vendor_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="mb-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <label for="file_metabox" class="form-label">file metabox</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" id="file_metabox" name="file_metabox[]" multiple="multiple">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <label for="file_cert" class="form-label">file Cert</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" id="file_cert" name="file_cert[]" multiple="multiple">
        </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

and here is the php

```
if (isset($_FILES['file_metabox'])) {
    $file_metabox = $_FILES['file_metabox'];
    foreach ($file_metabox['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($file_metabox['name'][$key]) {
            $file = array(
                'name' => $file_metabox['name'][$key],
                'type' => $file_metabox['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name' => $file_metabox['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error' => $file_metabox['error'][$key],
                'size' => $file_metabox['size'][$key]
            );
            $_FILES = array("file_metabox" => $file);
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                // $newupload = frontend_handle_attachment( $file, $post_success );
                if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

                $attach_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_success);

                add_post_meta($post_success, 'file_metabox', $attach_id);
            }
        }
    }
   
}
if (isset($_FILES['file_cert'])) {
    $file_cert = $_FILES['file_cert'];
    foreach ($file_cert['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($file_cert['name'][$key]) {
            $file = array(
                'name' => $file_cert['name'][$key],
                'type' => $file_cert['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name' => $file_cert['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error' => $file_cert['error'][$key],
                'size' => $file_cert['size'][$key]
            );
            $_FILES = array("file_cert" => $file);
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                // $newupload = frontend_handle_attachment( $file, $post_success );
                if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

                $attach_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_success);

                add_post_meta($post_success, 'file_cert', $attach_id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're overwriting the `$_FILES` array in your first `if()` statement: `$_FILES = array("file_metabox" => $file);`, so even if there *was* anything in the `$_FILES['file_cert']` variable, it's gone by the time your code checks it.

Comment: thanks for the reply, do you hve any ideas on how to fix this. thanks again

Comment: Use a different variable name than `$_FILES` in your code. Maybe something like `$_files` is what you're looking for (since PHP is case-sensitive.

Comment: That didnt work! As it using $_FILES array not just a random variable

Comment: See my answer, since I think this issue is a bit involved to explain in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is happening. I've added comments to the relevant sections of your code.

```
// You use the $_FILES superglobal to get the uploaded files.
if (isset($_FILES['file_metabox'])) {
    $file_metabox = $_FILES['file_metabox'];
    foreach ($file_metabox['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($file_metabox['name'][$key]) {
            // ...
            // Here you **overwrite** the $_FILES superglobal.
            $_FILES = array("file_metabox" => $file);
            //...           
        }
    }
   
}

// So here, $_FILES['file_cert'] **no longer exists**.
if (isset($_FILES['file_cert'])) {
// ...
}
```

I would recommend using a different variable name, so that you're not overwriting the content of `$_FILES`.

For example: replace

```
$_FILES = array("file_metabox" => $file);
```

with

```
$my_files = array("file_metabox" => $file);
```